# Gmail in MS Outlook 2010 - Prevent deletion of emails from server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail

I use my gmail account in my Microsoft outlook 2010 that is how it was set up.

Outlook is deleting emails and i battle to send emails at times.

how do i stop this from happening.

Today for the first time its the deleting started also i cannot retrieve something once it has been deleted it is gone.

Prior to today"s problem  it would become unresponsive and my outlook account would freeze and say not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

check `leave a copy of messages on server` in settings

uncheck `Remove from servera after days`

uncheck `Remove from server when deleted from 'deleted items'`

[image]

[Read full guide here](http://support.tigertech.net/outlook-2010-lmos)